# Errors Incorporating UI into Python Code

Tags: python, pyqt5

## Background:

I'm building this gui dictionary app using python and PyQt5.
**data.json** is the file containing keys and their definitions(data is arranged like a python dictionary).

dictionary.ui is the UI that i built in **pyqt5 designer app**

( widget class="**QMainWindow**" name="MainWindow"). (widget class="QPushButton" name="**pushButton**"). (widget class="QLineEdit" name="**lineEdit**").(widget class="QLabel" name="**resultArea**")

## Problem:

The program runs after a while showing gui. But when i enter something, the program crashes without an output. I'm having trouble fixing this code.

The problem is in this line of code ***self.resultArea.setText(self.trasnlate(self.lineEdit.text()))***
The error is `Translate is a method not a class instance`.

I need the user input that is entered in **lineEdit** label as an argument for **translate()** method and show the result of the method in **resultArea** label if the **pushButton** is clicked.

## Code:

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


data = json.load(open("data.json"))

class DictionaryApp(QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super(DictionaryApp,self).__init__()
        loadUi('dictionary.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dictionary')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self) :
        self.resultArea.setText(self.trasnlate(self.lineEdit.text()))
    @staticmethod
    def translate(w) :
        w = w.lower()
        if w in data :
            return data[w]
        elif w.title() in data: 
            return data[w.title()]
        elif w.upper() in data: 
            return data[w.upper()]
        elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0 :
            YN = input("Did you mean {} instead? Enter 'y' for yes, 'n' for no: ".format(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0])).lower()
            if YN == "y" :
                return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
            elif YN == "n" :
                return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it. "
            else :
                return "Wrong entry. "
        else :
            return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it. "     
        
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=DictionaryApp()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `self.resultArea.setText(self.trasnlate(self.lineEdit.text()))` to `self.resultArea.setText(self.lineEdit.text())`

Comment: @S.Nick thanks for replying. Your answer is putting the user entered data in my result label .But what i want is to pass the user entered data to method translate().

Comment: change `self.resultArea.setText(self.trasnlate(self.lineEdit.text()))` to `self.trasnlate(self.lineEdit.text())`

Comment: @S.Nick Thanks. I had actually missed the self. there .. Code is working now . Thanks man.